# Android notification are grouped for certain apps. Need separate notifications

Tags: android, notifications

I am reading all the notifications from status bar and storing it in my app. What i need is  1 liner for each notification which tells its descriptions. Like for gmail, its subject and few words of is body. It works fine when first notification comes . As soon as second notification comes and if first one is not read, the notification text gives as "2 Unread Messages" instead of the description it gave first time. It does not happen for all the apps. Gmail, Whatsapp are few examples which are giving this problem.

Note : I have crated an Accessibility Service which reads these notifications from status bar and parse its description.

Any help would be highly appreciated as I am stuck now with the development.

Comment: Do you means like this http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html

Comment: Thats correct Gina. I want to read the details of Stacked notifications.